# Getting an error for cerbot with docker-compose, nginx, gunicorn and django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, certbot

I am getting the below error when using certbot with nginx in ubuntu 18.04.

Error Details:

```
Attaching to certbot
certbot        | Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot        | Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
certbot        | Obtaining a new certificate
certbot        | Performing the following challenges:
certbot        | http-01 challenge for example.com
certbot        | http-01 challenge for www.example.com
certbot        | Using the webroot path /var/www/html for all unmatched domains.
certbot        | Waiting for verification...
certbot        | Challenge failed for domain example.com
certbot        | Challenge failed for domain www.example.com
certbot        | http-01 challenge for example.com
certbot        | http-01 challenge for www.example.com
certbot        | Cleaning up challenges
certbot        | Some challenges have failed.
certbot        | IMPORTANT NOTES:
certbot        |  - The following errors were reported by the server:
certbot        | 
certbot        |    Domain: example.com
certbot        |    Type:   connection
certbot        |    Detail: Fetching
certbot        |    http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/3xVDLqF-YtEGo99rqnsKGk5wiaP9ct-WtahxOetrCPc:
certbot        |    Connection refused
certbot        | 
certbot        |    Domain: www.example.com
certbot        |    Type:   connection
certbot        |    Detail: Fetching
certbot        |    http://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/zsONhLSTJF18mcGdXpKZ6_3BnKf_uaKg-0DYP2rGLi4:
certbot        |    Connection refused
certbot        | 
certbot        |    To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
certbot        |    entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
certbot        |    contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
certbot        |    your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
certbot        |    firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
certbot        |    client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
certbot        |    that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
root@oneuser:/home/oneuser/code/project# sudo docker-compose logs nginx
Attaching to nginx
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
nginx          | [2020-08-01 17:08:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
nginx          | Environment: Environment:  PROD
nginx          |  PROD
nginx          | Environment:  PROD
nginx          | Production settings importedProduction settings imported
nginx          | Production settings imported
nginx          |
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: web
    command: gunicorn project.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --log-level=debug --access-logfile=- --log-file=-
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
    # ports:
    #   - 1337:8000
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - redis
  
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  nginx:
    build: .
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      # - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      # - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - ./dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - web-root:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - web
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email oneuser@gmail.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d example.com  -d www.example.com

  celery:
    build: .
    container_name: celery
    command: celery -A project worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - redis
  
  celery-beat:
    build: .
    container_name: celery-beat
    command: celery -A project beat -l info
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
    env_file: .env
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - app-network
    depends_on:
      - redis

volumes:
  certs:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /home/oneuser/code/project/
      o: bind

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# ARG environment
ENV ENVIRONMENT='PROD'
ENV LOCAL_MIGRATIONS='NO'

RUN set -e; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    libffi-dev \
    libc-dev \
    mariadb-dev \
    python3-dev \
    musl-dev \
    ;

# set work directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN apk del .build-deps

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "3", "project.wsgi:application"]
```

All the services are running fine, except the certbot. Trying to resolve this issue since two days with different approaches even tried various approaches. Nothing is working  as expected.

When running `docker ps`:
Name                  Command               State                          Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
celery        celery -A project worker - ...   Up       8000/tcp
celery-beat   celery -A project beat -l info   Up       8000/tcp
certbot       certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 1
nginx         gunicorn --bind :8000 --wo ...   Up       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 8000/tcp
redis         docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up       6379/tcp
web           gunicorn project.wsgi -b 0 ...   Up       8000/tcp